# jQuery show and hide element without a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm currently trying to figure out how to use the .show() and .hide() functionality provided by jQuery to show and hide a div-class or a p-class containing some text, and I want to be able to click inside the div-parent to be able to show the context. Not to have a button but let's say i hover over a div-class containing a short text and a logo the background changes, and I want to be able to click on this class and show the hidden content inside parent-class.

I'll try to ilustrate this with the pictures below:

[image]

So after I click in the div-class this should extend the existing class and show the hidden content:

[image]

I hope someone can get me on the right track here and help me solve this.
Cheers

Comment: post some code. Have you tried something? What doesn't work?

Comment: Can you post some code you've written?

Comment: Please post all relevant code in OP not just an image

Comment: Could please add your tried code so that we could help you with...

Answer (score 1):

You could solve your concern in pure `CSS` on hover. Check if this is what you're looking for!

```
.content:hover, .content2:hover, .content3:hover {
   height: 200px;
}
```

or you can use jQuery!

> **Note:** This code is to retain the `transition` when the `div` expands with a dynamic height.

**Updated**

```js
jQuery.fn.animateAuto = function(prop, speed, callback){
    var elem, height;
    return this.each(function(i, el){
        el = jQuery(el), elem = el.clone().css({"height":"auto"}).appendTo("body");
        height = elem.css("height"),
        elem.remove();
        if(prop === "height")
            el.animate({"height":height}, speed, callback);
    });  
}

$("document").ready(function(){
  $(".content, .content2, .content3").hover(function(){
  var h = $(this).css("height");
    if(h == '50px'){
      $(this).animateAuto('height', 20);
    }
    else{
      $(this).css("height", '50px'); 
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.content, .content2, .content3 {
  padding: 5px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 25%;
  margin:0 2%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  transition: height 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: height 0.5s;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  background:#666;
  border-radius:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <h2>Div 1</h2> 
  <p>This is an example! This is an example!</p>
</div>

<div class="content2">
  <h2>Div 2</h2> 
  <p>This is an example! This is an example! This is an example! This is an example! This is an example2!</p>
</div>

<div class="content3">
  <h2>Div 3</h2> 
  <p>This is an example! This is an example!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, pure CSS would ofc be the best option.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So i think this will do it, however is there a way to extend the div-height based on the length of the content? let say that div1 has the double amount of content compaired to div2, but I don't want the height to be the same for both. I still want the fading effect to be there, tried to set height to relative or auto, but this seems to remove the transition?

Answer (score 0):

Rather simple to acchieve by using event handlers like hover or mouseenter.

```
$("div").hover(function(event){
 $(this).show();
  /*OR*/
 $(".selector").show();
});
```

You can find all the events here:

http://api.jquery.com/category/events/

... and all the mouse events here:

http://api.jquery.com/category/events/mouse-events/

Answer (score 0):

When the main container element is clicked find all of the children of the clicked element with the `hidden-text` class and show them.

```js
$(".hidden-text").hide();
$(".container").click(function() {
  $(".container").children(".hidden-text").hide();
  $(this).children(".hidden-text").show();  
})
```

```css
.container{
  width:100px;  
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">This is a div<div class="hidden-text">This is a bunch of hidden text in the div inside of another div.</div></div>
<div class="container">This is a div<div class="hidden-text">This is a bunch of hidden text in the div inside of another div.</div></div>
<div class="container">This is a div<div class="hidden-text">This is a bunch of hidden text in the div inside of another div.</div></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and sorry for the late response! So I've tried your solution, however how do I make only one of the div-block to be displayed at a time? Basicly if the opened div-container loses focus, I would like it to be hidden. For example if I show the first one and leave that one open, and then click on the second one I would like the first one to fade up again and be hidden. The same if I click somewhere inside the 'hidden-text' or on the opened 'container itself it should be hidden again.

Comment: Well yes, some of it, however if i click outside on the blank page, I would like to hide every opened div-block. is there a simpler way doing this than what I have come up with: 
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("body").click(function(e) {     
    if($(e.target).attr('class') === "container") {
          pass;
    }
    else {
        $(".container").children(".hidden-text").hide();
    }
  });
});

Answer (score 0):

Please do refer another way of approach using pure css

```
<div class="box-content">
  <h2>Div 1</h2> 
  <p>This is an example! This is an example! This is an example! This is an example! This is an example! This is an example! </p>
</div>

<div class="box-content">
  <h2>Div 2</h2> 
  <p>This is an example! This is an example! This is an example! This is an example! This is an example! This is an example! </p>
</div>

<div class="box-content">
  <h2>Div 3</h2> 
  <p>This is an example! This is an example! This is an example! This is an example! This is an example! This is an example! </p>
</div>


.box-content { padding: 5px; height: auto; width: 25%; margin: 0 2%; float: left; background: #666; border-radius: 5px; }
.box-content p { display: none; }
.box-content:hover p { display: block; color: #fff; }
```